# Dynamic height of tableviewcolumn according to text length

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

hello I have the following problem I am working with qt quick control 1.4 because the tableview of 2.15 does not adapt correctly as I would like; the table overflows in height and my question is the following can you make a dynamic height and that can be adding say 15 to the default height

example: the default height is  50

can you add 15 or 10 depending on the length of the text?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("TableView example")
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 400
    visible: true
    //[!addrowdata]

    /////////////////////////////
    ListModel {
        id: tablemode

        ListElement {
            number: "1"
            elevation_Max:"90000"
            elevation_Min:"50"
            length:"52-73\n122-163\n200-264\n280-317"
            depth:"8636-8900"
        }
        ListElement {
            number: "2"
            elevation_Max:"8000"
            elevation_Min:"21"
            length:"0-57\n119-166\n206-264"
            depth:"12700-13462"
        }
    }

        TableView{
            id :tableView
            anchors.fill: parent
            alternatingRowColors : false

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "number"
                title: "Number"
                width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "elevation_Max"
                title: "Elevation Max"
                width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "elevation_Min"
                title: "Elevation Min"
                width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount

                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "length"
                title: "Length"
                width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount

                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "depth"
                title: "Depth"
                width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount

                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            model: tablemode

            //Custom header proxy
            headerDelegate:Rectangle{
                color: "#0A1B2D"
                width: 100;
                height: 40
                border.color: "white"
                Text{
                    anchors.centerIn : parent
                    text: styleData.value
                    color: "#ffffff"
                    font.pixelSize: 15
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
            }

            //The line agent can modify the line height information
            rowDelegate: Rectangle {
                height: 50 // problem text protrudes out of the row
                color: "#052641"
                anchors.leftMargin: 2

            }
            itemDelegate: Rectangle{
                id: rectangle
                border.color: "white"
                border.width: 1
                color : styleData.selected ? "#white": "#394755" //Extern
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn : parent
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                    color : "#ffffff"
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    text: styleData.value
                    font.pixelSize: 14
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                }
            }

            style: TableViewStyle{
                textColor: "white"
                highlightedTextColor: "#00CCFE" //Selected color
                backgroundColor : "#f5f5f5"
            frame: Rectangle {
                border{
                    color: "#00000000" // color of the border
                }
            }
            handle: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                radius:20
                color: "#052641"//indicador en movimiento
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            decrementControl: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            incrementControl: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }

        }
        }
}
```

I have looked for different solutions and none of them fits the text, if you could help me I have been struggling with this for days I would appreciate it in advance.

Comment: If there are issues with the new TableView you should report them at [bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a property `maxSize` and modified it every time the `contentHeight` of one cell changes to something bigger than `maxSize`.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("TableView example")
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 400
    visible: true
    
    property int maxHeight: 50
    //[!addrowdata]
    
    /////////////////////////////
    ListModel {
        id: tablemode
        
        ListElement {
            number: "1"
            elevation_Max:"90000"
            elevation_Min:"50"
            length:"52-73\n122-163\n200-264\n280-317"
            depth:"8636-8900"
        }
        ListElement {
            number: "2"
            elevation_Max:"8000"
            elevation_Min:"21"
            length:"0-57\n119-166\n206-264"
            depth:"12700-13462"
        }
    }
    
    TableView{
        id :tableView
        anchors.fill: parent
        alternatingRowColors : false
        
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "number"
            title: "Number"
            width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "elevation_Max"
            title: "Elevation Max"
            width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "elevation_Min"
            title: "Elevation Min"
            width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
            
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "length"
            title: "Length"
            width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
            
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "depth"
            title: "Depth"
            width: tableView.viewport.width/tableView.columnCount
            
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        model: tablemode
        
        //Custom header proxy
        headerDelegate:Rectangle{
            color: "#0A1B2D"
            width: 100;
            height: 40
            border.color: "white"
            Text{
                anchors.centerIn : parent
                text: styleData.value
                color: "#ffffff"
                font.pixelSize: 15
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
        
        //The line agent can modify the line height information
        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            height: maxHeight // problem text protrudes out of the row
            color: "#052641"
            anchors.leftMargin: 2
            
        }
        itemDelegate: Rectangle{
            id: rectangle
            border.color: "white"
            border.width: 1
            color : styleData.selected ? "#white": "#394755" //Extern
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn : parent
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                color : "#ffffff"
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                text: styleData.value
                font.pixelSize: 14
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                
                onContentHeightChanged: {
                    if (contentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = contentHeight;
                }
            }
        }
        
        style: TableViewStyle{
            textColor: "white"
            highlightedTextColor: "#00CCFE" //Selected color
            backgroundColor : "#f5f5f5"
            frame: Rectangle {
                border{
                    color: "#00000000" // color of the border
                }
            }
            handle: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                radius:20
                color: "#052641"//indicador en movimiento
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            decrementControl: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            incrementControl: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "#00000000"
                border.color:"#00000000"
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this hacky solution would look like this:
[image]